# Поиск индекса по Guid в List

Tags: c#

Есть List следующих объектов Employee

```
    class Employee
        {
            public Guid Guid { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Как можно получить индекс элемента Employee в List по его Guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем индекс, если можно сам элемент сразу?

[List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find)

```
Employee employee = list.Find(x => x.Guid == guid);
```

Ок, если нужен индекс, то вот так.

[List<T>.IndexOf(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof)

```
int index = list.IndexOf(employee);
```

Читайте документацию по классам .NET, там много всего полезного.

Comment: Только IndexOf в данном примере отработает правильно, т.к. employee получен из листа, а если создать новый ```var employee = new Employee { Guid = Guid.NewGuid()  }```, то метод вернет -1, нужно переопределить еще Equals у Employee